# Sums of divisors of powers of 2

Tags: number-theory

As an example of what I am wondering, $\sigma(16)=\sigma(25)=31$. That made me wonder if there are other powers of $2$ which have sums of divisors equal to the sums of divisors of an odd square?

Comment: And besides wondering, what are your thoughts? You are aware that $\sigma(2^n)=2^{n+1}-1$?

Comment: My thoughts were to look for any occurrences where they overlap but it is tedious

Comment: I tried to check on wolfram but it only gave me the case I already have

Comment: This seems difficult as it involves knowing the factors of Mersenne numbers $(2^k-1)$ when $k$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you Alex R I think you get what I am stuck on

Comment: @AlexR.:I would think it's even worse, the expression $\sigma(n^2)$ on the other side of the equation involves sums and products in non-trivial ways in general, so even knowing a complete factorisation of $2^k-1$ might not be very helpful.

Comment: At least the case where the odd base is a prime, like your case here, is covered by the Goormaghtigh Conjecture. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599653/on-uniqueness-of-sums-of-prime-powers